# using for/while loops in anonymous functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, anonymous-function

I have found anonymous function pretty useful, but a lot of times I'll need to use a loop in order to make the function work. For example:

```
while val<tolerance
     .....
end
```

I am aware that I can save the function in a separate file, and that sometimes I can vectorize the code and then the anonymous function can work, but in some cases it is very hard to find an alternative to  a for loop.

Matlab documentation doesn't discuss it or say it is impossible. Any ideas?

Comment: I have never found a way to use multi-line commands (`while`,`if`,`for` etc) in an anonymous function.  I sometimes created functionalized versions of those commands just for this purpose, for example a standalone function `out = iff(condition, trueoutput, falseoutput)`, or in your case, perhaps `out = whilef(fnCondition, fnExecute, fnOutput)`.

Comment: Now I kind of what to spend a few hours writing functionalized forms of the main command flow commands.  But I must resist, or no real work will ever be accomplished.

Comment: cool question (+1) and comment, @Pursuit, if you can do an `iff` standalone function, I think there's a good chance to answer Lama's question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Functional Programming](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs) constructs on the Mathworks file exchange are precisely what you need. Each of these functions are designed to be used within anonymous functions. They are discussed in detail in a 3 part series on the *Loren on the Art of MATLAB* Blog: [Part 1](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/),  [Part 2](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/) and [Part 3](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/07/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-3/).

In particular [Part 3](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/07/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-3/) discusses implementing loops as a function. For completeness, I will borrow some of the code from [Functional Programming FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs) to demonstrate how in m-code we can use a while loop within an anonymous function. Firstly, define a `loop` function:

```
   function x = loop(x, continueFcn, f)
   % Inputs:
   % x           - Initial state (can be cell array of arguments to f)
   % continueFcn - Continue function, returns true iff the loop should go on
   % f           - Function of the state (x) to run every iteration
       while ~continueFcn(x{:})
           x = f(x{:});
       end
   end
```

For the example provide `val` wile have some initial value, `val0` say. Further, suppose that `StuffDoneEachWhileLoop` is a function that defines how the variable `val` should update in each while loop. Then:

```
myFunc = @(n) loop(val0, ...                    % Initialize state
                  @(val) val < tolerance, ...   % OP condition
                  @(val) StuffDoneEachWhileLoop(val));    %
```

Various extensions to the above idea are possible. See Tucker McClure's [Functional Programming FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

If your main bother is having to create a new m file each time you want to use a simple function, this could be a simple solution for you.

If you are writing a function, and want to use another function in only this scope you do not need to create a new m file. Instead you can just define a second function which is available locally.

Check this for example:

```
function [m,s] = stat2(x)
n = length(x);
m = avg(x,n);
s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n));
end

function m = avg(x,n)
m = sum(x)/n;
end
```

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/function.html;jsessionid=903a612c197e288e7cf631d7a434

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's documentation actually does discuss it, however the explanation might be considered somewhat vague. From the [anonymous function documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

> Anonymous functions can accept inputs and return outputs, just as
>   standard functions do. However, they can contain *only a
>   single executable statement*.

What I understand under "executable statement" is actually an expression that obtains some value.

As far as I know, loops in Matlab do not have a value and therefore cannot be used as the single executable statement inside an anonymous function. Furthermore, the constraint of just a *single* statement means that you cannot use the loop for some computation and then return some value with a second statement inside the anonymous function.